# Find the accent data in table records

Tags: sql, oracle

In a table, I have a column that contains a few records with accented characters. I want a query to find the records with accented characters.

If we have records like as below:

```
2ème édition
Natália
sravanth
```

query should pick these records:

```
2ème édition
Natália
```

Comment: Add some sample data and your expected result ;).

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I didn't asked for stored procedure, I asked oracle query

Comment: You asked for PL/SQL code - that **is** a stored procedure

Comment: When you say `ascent`, do you mean `accented characters` (in french: caractères avec accent)?  Like `é` or `í`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how replace accented letter in a varchar2 column in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837263/how-replace-accented-letter-in-a-varchar2-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REGEXP_LIKE function along with a list of all the accented characters you're interested in:

```
with t1(data) as (
  select '2ème édition' from dual union all
  select 'Natália' from dual union all
  select 'sravanth' from dual
)
select * from t1 where regexp_like(data,'[àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]');

DATA         
--------------
2ème édition  
Natália
```

Comment: I suspect that you are right about what OP meant by `ascent`, and I noticed that you proposed an edit to reword his question.  But let's confirm with OP first to clear up his intent.

Comment: Thanks for answer. even this will work  with t1(data) as (
  select '2ème édition' from dual union all
  select 'Natália' from dual union all
  select 'sravanth' from dual
)
select * from t1 where REGEXP_like(ASCIISTR(data), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}')

Comment: @SravanthKothuri yes if you use this `'\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}'` match expression (note the double `\\`).  The back slash character is an escape character in string data in oracle, so to use the backslash in your string expressions you have to escape it with another backslash.

Answer (score 4):

The [ASCIISTR function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ASCIISTR.html) would be another way to find accented characters

> ASCIISTR takes as its argument a string, or an expression that
>   resolves to a string, in any character set and returns an ASCII
>   version of the string in the database character set. Non-ASCII
>   characters are converted to the form \xxxx, where xxxx represents a
>   UTF-16 code unit.

So you can do something like

```
SELECT my_field FROM my_table
WHERE NOT my_field = ASCIISTR(my_field)
```

Or to re-use the demo from the accepted answer:

```
with t1(data) as (
  select '2ème édition' from dual union all
  select 'Natália' from dual union all
  select 'sravanth' from dual
)
select * from t1 where data != asciistr(data)
```

which would output the 2 rows with accents.

Answer (score 1):

with t1(data) as (
      select '2ème édition' from dual union all
      select 'Natália' from dual union all
      select 'sravanth' from dual
    )
    select * from t1 where REGEXP_like(ASCIISTR(data), '\ \ [[:xdigit:]]{4}');

```
DATA         
--------------
2ème édition  
Natália
```

Answer (score -1):

Way harder than it seems on the surface as there is more than one way to create an accent.   What I do is have a mirror column I call clean and scrub out all the accents on load.

See this question I asked some time ago  [normalized string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300155/normalized-string-is-not-the-same-as-tochararray)

Comment: And a second down vote.  WOW.  I do exactly this with a production commercial application.   I am not going to delete just because you don't understand.

Comment: I think your first sentence is important, and have upvoted on that basis. Maybe the downvotes are because you haven't really answered the question though - asker wants a `SQL` query and you've posted a general approach which makes use of `.NET`.